# Random change of node order in GraphViz/dot

Tags: graphviz, dot

I am trying to paint a little graph in GraphViz/dot.
The boxes "Team 1", "Turnier32" and "Team 2" should be on one horizontal level.
"Team 1" points right to "Turnier32", "Team 2" to the left.
I want the ellipses "Name1", "2015-11-14" and "Name2" below the corresponding nodes. There should only be straight horizontal and vertical edges. 
My current approach is this:

```
digraph turnier{
ordering=out ;
subgraph {
    rank=same;
    T1  [shape="box", label="Team 1"];
    TOURNAMENT  [shape="box", label="Turnier32"];
    T2  [shape="box", label="Team 2"];

}
subgraph {
    rank=same;
    N1  [shape="ellipse", label="Name1"];
    DATE  [shape="ellipse", label="2015-11-14"];
    N2  [shape="ellipse", label="Name2"];
}

T1 -> N1 [label="hasName"];
TOURNAMENT -> DATE [label="occuredOnDate"];
T2 -> N2 [label="hasName"];
T1 -> TOURNAMENT [label="attended"];
T2 -> TOURNAMENT [label="attended"];
}
```

[image]
GraphViz reordered T1, TOURNAMENT and T2 to T1, T2, TOURNAMENT, which is not, what I want. If i strike out the last two edges, the order is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add to your last line [`constraint=false`](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:constraint):

```
T2 -> TOURNAMENT [label="attended", constraint=false];
```